# Client SocketInputStream.close() leads to more resource consumption?

Tags: java, windows, performance, sockets

If I execute the JUnit test below WITHOUT the line "inputStream.close()" (see below), more than 60000 requests can be processed (I killed the process then). WITH this line, I did not manage making more than 15000 requests, because of:

```
java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
    at SocketTest.callServer(SocketTest.java:60)
    at SocketTest.testResourceConsumption(SocketTest.java:52)
```

I run it on Windows, before starting the test I wait for the netstat list to be back to normal.

Questions:

- why is calling socketInputStream.close() on the client side harms in this case?
- or what is wrong with the code?

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class SocketTest extends TestCase {
    private static final int PORT = 12345;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                                    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                                        outputStream.write(i);
                                    }
                                    outputStream.close();
                                    // in fact the previous line calls this already:
                                    // socket.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void testResourceConsumption() throws Exception {
        for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
            callServer();
            if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void callServer() throws Exception {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", PORT);
        InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            assertEquals(i, inputStream.read());
        }
        ///////////////// THIS LINE IS INTERESTING 
        inputStream.close();
        // in fact the previous line calls this already:
        // clientSocket.close();
    }

    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        serverSocket.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sure you don't have this back to front?

Comment: Can you provide more information about Windows version, platform 32 or 64 bits, and java version?

Comment: Just for reference, I ran your test on Ubuntu 15.04. It completed all million iterations without error. Roughly 28000 sockets existed in state TIME_WAIT at any given time during the execution. (this is due to the speed of execution and opening of new sockets)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you explicitly call `inputStream.close()` you change the order of TCP graceful connection release. In this case the client side of the connection is closed prior to receiving FIN packet  from the server, thus leaving the socket in TIME_WAIT state. At some point all local ports for outgoing connections become occupied with these TIME_WAIT sockets, and no more outgoing connections can be made.

When you don't call `inputStream.close()`, the connections are shut down by the server side with `outputStream.close()` call. The client sockets have enough time to receive FIN from the server, and then at garbage collection time they get gracefully closed by the finalizer method.

There are two options to fix the procedure in your test:

1. Preferable way is to continue reading from `inputStream` until you receive -1, which means that the other side has initiated the connection shutdown (i.e. FIN is received). Just insert `assertEquals(-1, inputStream.read());` before `inputStream.close();`
2. The second option is to force the abortive release by setting
   `clientSocket.setSoLinger(true, 0);`
   In this case `inputStream.close()` will force client to send RST and abort the connection.

[More about orderly and abortive TCP connection release.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/articles/connection_release.html)

Comment: For reference, only the second option (force close) worked for me on Java 8 on OSX.